# Layout with Label, Inputfield, and Checkbox

Tags: sapui5

### Mockup

[image: Mockup]

### Current Code

```
<mvc:View
  xmlns="sap.m"
  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
  xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
  xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form"
  displayBlock="true" height="100%">
  <Page showHeader="false" id="page">
    <content>
      <l:Grid defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12" width="auto">
        <l:content>
          <f:Form editable="true">
            <f:title>
              <core:Title text="Test" />
            </f:title>
            <f:layout>
              <f:ResponsiveGridLayout
                labelSpanL="3"
                labelSpanM="3"
                emptySpanL="4"
                emptySpanM="4"
                columnsL="1"
                columnsM="1"
              />
            </f:layout>
            <f:formContainers>
              <f:FormContainer>
                <f:formElements>
                  <f:FormElement label="Name">
                    <f:fields>
                      <Input id="name1" value="" />
                    </f:fields>
                  </f:FormElement>
                  <f:FormElement label="Name">
                    <f:fields>
                      <Input id="name2" value="" />
                    </f:fields>
                  </f:FormElement>
                  <f:FormElement>
                    <f:fields>
                      <CheckBox id="cb1" />
                      <Text wrapping="true" text="lorem ipsum" />
                    </f:fields>
                  </f:FormElement>
                </f:formElements>
              </f:FormContainer>
            </f:formContainers>
          </f:Form>
        </l:content>
      </l:Grid>
    </content>
  </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

### Problem

The checkbox is not centered. The current code is responsive and the solution should also be responsive.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "checkbox is not centered"? In the mockup, the checkbox isn't centered either..

Answer (score 0):

If you want the checkbox to be centered you need to use a label on your formElement just as you do with the others. If you don't want a label you will probably need some css to put a left-margin on that specific FormElement.

There is maybe another way more "polite" to do that, but if it exists I do not know it, will keep looking at that post to see if someone actually offers a better solution.

But for now, I hope this works for you for the moment.